# Google Plus login button on Android using AppInventor

Tags: android

I am sure there will tutorials out there to integrate Google plus login button using Java Android. I want to implement it using MIT AppInventor2.

Also after adding Google plus login what is the best practices to store user details in tinydb a database of AppInventor. I am new to Android.

Comment: This is Too Broad or Unclear for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. You could create an image button that opens the webbrowser with your google+ page.